# Rewriting HTTP method with ASP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, http, rest

Because most browsers only support HTTP GET and POST it would be useful to have a HttpHandler that can rewrite the HTTP method.

The HTTP method would be set with a hidden field:

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  ...
</form>
```

If the user submits, a POST request is sent and an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) should replace the requests HttpMethod, but it is a [read-only property in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx).

How can I rewrite the HTTP method in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mvc (ver 2+) you can use the HtmlHelper.HttpMethodOverride helper, which creates a hidden input value with the required action method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402924.aspx

this creates this hidden input (for delete):
`<input name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" type="hidden" value="DELETE" />`

some more info:

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/01/08/implementing-a-delete-link-with-mvc-2-and-httpmethodoverride.aspx

UPDATE:

Looking a bit deeper into how this works in the MVC pipeline it's actually MVC (ActionMethodSelectorAttribute, ActionInvoker,RedirectToRoute) that handles this and not the 
RouteModule like I thought before.

You can look it up in the MVC source (from codeplex)... It's quite strightforward. The more interesting parts are in HttpRequestBaseExtensions and HttpRequestExtensions

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server side of the equation already, why not write a proxy server to do this for you? You could use something like [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) to do the heavy lifting.

It would be reusable across a wide range of applications and would not necessarily need to be specific to IIS and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType`. This property is not read only and you can change it on the c#.

For more information, [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requesttype(v=vs.110).aspx).